# Decoding single kubernetes secret using powershell

Tags: powershell, kubernetes

I've managed to get my hands on a Powershell one liner that will get all kubernetes secrets and base64 decode them.

```
kubectl get secrets -o json | ConvertFrom-Json | select -ExpandProperty items | ? data | select -ExpandProperty data | % { $_.PSObject.Properties | % { $_.Name + [System.Environment]::NewLine + [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($_.Value)) + [System.Environment]::NewLine + [System.Environment]::NewLine } }
```

The above works.
I've been playing with trying to modify this command to work for a single secret like below without luck:

```
kubectl get secret mysecretname -o json | ConvertFrom-Json | select -ExpandProperty items | ? data | select -ExpandProperty data | % { $_.PSObject.Properties | % { $_.Name + [System.Environment]::NewLine + [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($_.Value)) + [System.Environment]::NewLine + [System.Environment]::NewLine } }
```

Could someone share their knowledge with me to help me through this one?

thanks

Comment: Can you show sample output (with dummy secrets) of `kubectl get secrets -o json`?

Comment: Related to what @MathiasR.Jessen said, when given a _single `Secret`_, it will not be `.items[]` because it's only one; the top-level key will be `.data` so you cane remove the `ExpandProperty items | ? data |` portions of your PS pipeline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you @mdaniel your suggestion solved this for me.

```
kubectl get secret mysecretname -o json | ConvertFrom-Json | select -ExpandProperty data | % { $_.PSObject.Properties | % { $_.Name + [System.Environment]::NewLine + [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($_.Value)) + [System.Environment]::NewLine + [System.Environment]::NewLine } }
```